# show random image from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select random images from imgArray to print 16 different images at the same time but can't fill the imgRandom function.

```
img = new imgArray(7);
img[0]='1.png';
img[1]='2.png';
img[2]='3.png';
img[3]='4.png';
img[4]='5.png';
img[5]='6.png';
img[6]='7.png';
img[7]='8.png';

var rand=imgArray[math.floor(math.random*imgArray.length)];

function imgRandom(){

}
```

Comment: You have just 8 elements in the array, how will you show 16 images?

Comment: same image can be seen twice

Comment: As it is random, will it look ok if same two images are side by side. Just my thought...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this function

```
function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
```

Call the function

```
getRandomImage(ARRAY-VARIABLE, '/images/')
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/JmYpZ/)**. You will see change in image for every refresh

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
var imgArray = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png'];
var basePath="YOUR_FOLDER_PATH_HERE";

function imgRandom() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        var rand = imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = basePath+rand;
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SJ4rY/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ4rY/)

Answer (score 2):

There are some things in your code i would like to point out

- There is no `imgArray` in javascript per default (maybe its a constructor of your's)
- You want an `Array`
- Javascript is case sensitiv, and the `Math` object in js has an capital M

  - `math` -> `Math`
- And the `random` propertie of the `Math` object, has to be invoked to return a random number

  - `random` -> `random()`
  - `Math.random()`

But to your Question

1. functions take parameters, so could take one param for an array of images

   `function (imgArr) {...`
   *With this you have access to the passed parameter throug `imgArr`*
2. function can return values, so taken `Math.random` we can go on

   function (imgArr) {
       return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length)]
   }
3. You don't have to "Dim" Array, and predefine the Elements you gonna put in, you can just do sth. like

   `var imgArr = ["img01.png","img02.png",...]`
   *And `var arr=[]` would be equals `var arr = new Array()`*
4. So calling this function with your Array couldlook like

---

```
  var img = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png"]
     function imgRandom(imgArr) {
        return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length)];
    }
 console.log(imgRandom(img));
```